# Silverstripe Live to Dev

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, localhost, silverstripe

I am trying to get a live site into a dev mode so I can make changes in a non live environment then re upload it back.
There error I am getting is
"This site can’t be reached refused to connect."
What is also strange is the site points to HTTPS evan after removing everything from my htaccess file

- I have downloaded all the files into a directory
- changed the database connections
- exported and imported the database into my php myadmin

Comment: But not checked the database for stored urls!

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: With dev-mode you mean this? https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3/developer_guides/debugging/environment_types/
Is there something (like Director::forceSSL()) in mysite/_config that could force a redirect in your dev-env?
Check your servers appache/php log-files!

Comment: Seems like you cannot reach your local server or the webroot? If you place an index.html in your webroot, can you reach this file?

Comment: @RiggsFolly SilverStripe normally doesn't save hardcoded URLS in DB (like other popular systems do) but a shortcode to the Site which will be rendered on-the-fly. So we can exclude this problem with 99%.